Cannot load file or assembly after upgrade to .NET 8.0
I have a Class Library project targeting .NET Framework 4.8. I used the .NET Upgrade Assistant extension in Visual Studio to upgrade it to target .NET 8.0. After fixing a number of errors that resulted from this change, I'm left with a single persistent error:

'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.
They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)'

I've tried resolutions in the answers to this question such as deleting bin/obj files and rebuilding, as well as clearing out dependent assembly entries in App.config. I tried installing the System.Runtime nuget package (though, I would think that's installed by default?) and this did not change the error. This answer suggested installing System.ServiceModel.Primitives, but that also did not change anything.
I'm at a bit of a loss. I'm not sure what else I can do to resolve this error. Further, I'm not really sure what the error is trying to tell me. Any guidance on that would be appreciated!

Might be a dependency that depends on that assembly.

@mxmissile in such a scenario, how would I go about finding the dependency and resolving this issue?

Check NuGet package manager for outdated/deprecated/incompatible.. packages

"as well as clearing out dependent assembly entries in App.config." - .NET Core should not use use App.config so changes to it should be irrelevant. Do you have a [mre]?

@MustafaMutasim Nuget package manager has no offending packages

@GuruStron creating a blank .NET Framework 4.8 project and upgrading it doesn't produce the same error, so I imagine it has to do with an installed package or something of the like. I am working on creating an MRE.

I generated a blank 4.8 project, installed all the packages from my own project, and upgraded. This also did not cause an error. What could the source of this error be besides packages?

If you are using nuget package,
in package manager web site check for your project supporting framework version,
for example, some packages support fully version of .net framework but on .Net it support versions before 7.0
it is same for the class library
Maybe your dll is not supporting in .net 8
try .net 7 or 6 or less for your project
Or ask the programmer of the project to upgrade their dll's .net version
@Chrygore

Ensure all the NuGet packages are updated to the latest version.  Next, check which packages and their dependencies are incompatible with .NET 8.0.  You can check the version compatibility information of any Nuget package in this:https://www.nuget.org/

Post your .csproj file.

I was able to resolve this issue.
The problem was actually being caused by an outdated license file being used by one of my packages (ActiveReports). Deleting the invalid license file caused it to be regenerated, which fixed the error I was experiencing.

As I mentioned in comments One of the solutions is changing your or the dll version of .Net, But the another thing is that in your current project Create another class library which is compatible with your dll or class library and try to use the code from the second class library or dll  in your main project

I'll give this a shot ASAP, however, we do need to upgrade to 8.0, since 7.0 and earlier are no longer supported by MS.
